# WKInterfaceController title alignment change on watchOS 10

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos, wkinterfacecontroller, watchos-10

I use setTitle() to display a custom text on the top left corner (aligned to the clock) of a controller. But after upgrading to watchOS 10, the title is displayed on the right, under the clock, pushing all the design down.

Is there a workaround to make the title behave as it did on older versions?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?  Did you find a solution?